# Disable page transition on data-role="header" at jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to disable page transition on data-role="header"?

The goal would be to use page transition only at data-role="content".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do this by making all your headers fixed and adding the same data-id attribute.

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>Hello world</p> 
        <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">link</a>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>Page 2</p>
        <a href="#page3" data-transition="slide">Page 3</a>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page3">

    <div data-role="header" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>page 3</p>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/7uJfv/1/

​

Comment: Your example works fine on iPad but doesn't work on iPhone.

Comment: Yes, is this solution supported only by iOS5?

Comment: Unfortunately fixed toolbars in general don't work for ios4 :(