# HTML5 - keep the header and footer stable between page transition

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Is there a way to keep the header and footer of the page stable and move only the content part of a page in jquerymobile on transition between two pages?

I have the following two pages

```
    page1.html
     <header>
       ....
     </header>

     <content>
       ....<!--content1-->
     </content>

     <footer>
       .....
     </footer>

     page2.html
      <header>
       ....
     </header>

     <content>
       ....<!--content2-->
     </content>

     <footer>
       .....
     </footer>
```

Logic:

- I need to use slide transition between pages.
- Am using JQueryMobile, phoneGap

Questions:

- How to retain the header and footer in the page stable? i.e only the content part moves on transition
- I expect it to work on ios and android devices.
- Is there any css way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable page transition on data-role="header" at jQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380840/disable-page-transition-on-data-role-header-at-jquery-mobile).

Comment: make there "position: fixed" , that will do work

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I used that answer before but it increases my page height by the height of the header. How to control this behaviour?

Comment: @wikijames are you telling the css property?

Answer (score 0):

use data-id and data-position to keep the header and footer of the page stable and move only the content do like that in header and footer

```
<div data-role = 'header' data-id="persistent" data-position='fixed' data-tap-toggle="false"  data-theme = 'b'>
```

Comment: I used that answer before but it increases my page height by the height of the header. How to control this behaviour?